# SharePoint Designer 2013 Send e-mail with specified FROM address

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, json

I tried to recreate a workflow in SPD2013 following advice there [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2014/10/24/you-cant-specify-the-from-address-for-email-messages-when-you-use-the-send-an-email-option-from-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-action/) It was Call HTTP Web service action that recreates JSON code. When I run this site workflow, I don't get any e-mails. I traced the sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail via FIddler and got 500 Internal server error.

Does someone has this issue before?

I am novice in SPD 2013. Maybe I do something wrong?

Can It be issue with SMPT server configured on Sharepoint farm?

Comment: Did you configured outgoing email in central admin?

Comment: Yes, it was configured. In usual workflow, I can send e-mails using E-mail action and get them.